# React MaterialUI - Set error on TextField Component after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-ui

I have an input form that I want to validate the input fields of once a 'search' button is clicked.

Most answers I have seen are having the input validated live, as the user enters it into the form.
I don't want to do this as some of the validation I need to do is a costly operation (validating an API key for example), therefore constantly checking it as it's entered is not an option.
This is also a serverless, single page application, and as far as I could tell - `onSubmit` would reload the page, so I'm not using that.

I have a simple form that looks similar to this:

```
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
    .......
    function handleFormChange(event) {
        let data = formData;
        data[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        setFormData(data);
    }
    ........
    <form id="search-form" >
       <TextField name="apiKey" label="API Key" onChange={handleFormChange} defaultValue={formData.apiKey} />
       <TextField name='itemName' label="Enter Item" onChange={handleFormChange} />
       <Button name='search-button' onClick={validate} >Search</Button>
    </form>
```

I can't work out what to put into `validate()` to either set the errors on the text fields or perform the search.
I've tried passing a function into the `error` prop that checks to see if an `errors` state variable is populated, I've tried looking into using refs to set the error state but I couldn't see any function that would set the error state.

The formData variable will hold the current data, so it's easy to check 'is this data valid' but for the life of me, I can't work out how to manually trigger the error state.

*I'm using React hooks FYI*

Answer (score 10):

Implement a `validation` function and call it when you submit your form. Maintain a state for `error` and update it when form is invalid. Use material UI [error](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#validation) prop to display errors beside your fields.

[Working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-validation-21nyq?file=/src/MyForm.js)

**Code Snippet**

```js
export default () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    apiKey: "test"
  });
  const [isFormInvalid, setIsFormInvalid] = useState(false);

  const validate = values => {
    if (values.apiKey !== "") {
      setIsFormInvalid(false);
    } else {
      setIsFormInvalid(true);
    }
  };
  function handleFormChange(event) {
    let data = formData;
    data[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setFormData(data);
  }
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate(formData)) {
      // proceed to submit
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="col-sm-12">
      <h1>My Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="search-form">
        <TextField
          error={isFormInvalid}
          helperText={isFormInvalid && "api key required"}
          name="apiKey"
          label="API Key"
          onChange={handleFormChange}
          defaultValue={formData.apiKey}
        />

        <Button type="submit" name="search-button" onClick={validate}>
          Search
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for showing me that - it's obvious once you see the solution. Thank you for showing me how to execute onSubmit, I noticed `validate()` was being called twice now, once for the `onClick` and once for the `onSubmit`. To help others in the future, you could remove one from the answer.

Comment: @gdh your `validate` function wasn't returning a value. It should return a `boolean` since you are calling the function inside an `if` statement. Also, the default value of "TEST" inside the `formData` constant is not needed and it is confusing. The original code, was failing the initial validation when empty string was passed because the variable was undefined. It only worked after the first successful validation. I still upvoted your answer because, despite all that, it was very helpful. So thank you so much for your answer.