# Passing multiple functions to onClick prop of a button (validation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a text field to enter a title in a dialog modal. There a button called 'create' that when clicked both adds an item to a table AND closes the dialog modal.

```
<Button onClick={createProjectButtonHandler} variant="contained">
```

And the function that handles this is:

```
  const createProjectButtonHandler = () => {
    props.onSaveProjectData(projectData);
    props.onCloseModal();

    setProjectTitle("");
  };
```

Here is my title validation function and state:

```
// title validation state and handler
  const [titleError, setTitleError] = useState(false);

  const validateTitle = (title) => {
    return title === 0 ? setTitleError(true) : setTitleError(false);
  };
```

Here my input field:

```
  <TextField
    label="Title"
    variant="outlined"
    required
    onChange={projectTitleHandler}
    error={titleError}
    helperText={titleError && "Please enter a title"}
  ></TextField>
```

How do I add this validation function to the `createProjectButtonHandler` function so that these two: `props.onSaveProjectData(projectData); props.onCloseModal();` only happen when titleError is false, otherwise when clicking the button and titleError is true I want to show that error.

In short, I want to validate the input text AFTER clicking the button. If no errors, then proceed.

Comment: How do you use input?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useForm} from "react-hook-form"; 
 const { register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm();

const submitForm = (data) => {
 props.onSaveProjectData(data);
    props.onCloseModal();

    setProjectTitle("");
}



<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
                <Grid item>
                  <TextField
                    name="Title"
                    label="title"
                    type={"text" }
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                    error={!!errors.Title}
                    helperText="Please enter a title"
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Button type="submit">
                      submit
                    </Button>
                 </Grid>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work. Is there a way to do it using native react hooks like useEffect? Without using a 3rd party package?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847276/react-materialui-set-error-on-textfield-component-after-button-is-clicked

Comment: Thanks I did check out this link; however, it wasn't what I was exactly looking for. I did end up making it work by using an if statement in the clickHandler that sets the error to true and used a useEffect hook to clean up the error when the modal windows is closed.